# Deleting characters from left side of a string in KSH

Tags: ksh

I have a string:

(string1) "String2_With_More_Parts"

and need the (string1) deleted from my variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
echo '(string1) "String2_With_More_Parts"' | sed -e s/\(string1\)\ //
```

This gives the output:

```
"String2_With_More_Parts"
```